# FormsAuthentication redirecting to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm trying to implement `Simple FormsAuthentication` in an `ASP.NET` **MVC5** application as:

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult login(Login login)
{            
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(login.username, login.password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(login.username, false);                 
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Invalid username or password. Try again");
            return View();
        }
     }
     return View("Index");            
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
<system.web>    
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms
              name="PC"
              loginUrl="~/Home/login"
              timeout="2">
          <credentials>
              <user name="admin" password="admin1"/>
          </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
```

Now when I supply correct credentials as mentioned in `Web.Config` file, error message from the `Else` statement part of `PostHttp login ViewResult` executes and writes message
`Invalid username or password. Try again` 
and redirects to login page again. URL shown in the browser is:

`http://payroll.net:81/Home/login?ReturnUrl=%2f`

Any idea why FormsAuthentication is not redirecting to "Index" View after receiving correct credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are Supplying it with the unhashed Password , The Default Hashing algorithm is Sha1 try Hashing your Password And put the hashed string.
Also if you do not want to use Encryption you can state it with :

```
 <credentials passwordFormat = "Clear">   
     <user name="UserName" 
     password="SimplePass"/>
  </credentials>
```

Comment: Thank you @mahdi mahzuni. Your answer did solve my problem.